# android textview return null error exception

Tags: android, textview, nullpointerexception

```
public class .. {

TextView txt;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.booom);
    doMethod();
}

ClassOne classOne = new ClassOne();
private void doMethod() {
    classOne.refire(this, classTwo);
}

public ClassTwo classTwo = new ClassTwo (){
    public void nomnom(Double ing){
        txt.setText(String.valueOf(ing); //null point error
    }
}
```

`txt.setText(String.valueOf(ing);` return null pointer error expection once the program is run, if i used `toast` in there without using `txt.setText`, its working fine.

What would be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you didn't close the parentheses: `txt.setText(String.valueOf(ing));`

Comment: I will be surprised if you can compile the code as your code contain error. You're missing the last enclosing bracket ')' at the line 'txt.setText(String.valueOf(ing);'

Answer (score 1):

Probably `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.booom);` returned null. Make sure that **booom** is the id of the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that ing is null. String.valueOf throws a NullPointerException is you pass it null.